# Rationalizing radical expressions

Tags: radicals

> $\sqrt [ 3 ]{\frac{3}{4}  }$  is the expression.
>   What i did was change it to an equivalent fraction $({\sqrt [ 3 ]{\frac{6}{8}  }=\frac{\sqrt [ 3 ]{  6}}{2} } )$. But i think it isn't right.
>   Please help me.

Comment: So what did you do exactly?

Comment: i chaged it to 3/4 to 6/8 to get a perfect cube, my answer is cube root of 6/2. is it right?

Comment: You phrased it wrong but I think you are correct. It's the cube root of 6 and that quantity divided by 2

Comment: As LaTeX'ed, looks perfectly good. Right strategy, right result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did this,
you were correct
(writing out every possible step):

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{4}}
=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2\times 3}{2\times 4}}
=\sqrt[3]{\frac{6}{8}}
=\frac{\sqrt[3]{6}}{\sqrt[3]{8}}
=\frac{\sqrt[3]{6}}{2}
$$